# XSLT-1.0 can a variable be used to access to other nodes?

Tags: variables, expression, nodes, xslt-1.0

With a simple XML like this

```
<value>
    <num>
        <accession>111</accession>
        <sequence>AAA</sequence>
        <score>4000</score>
    </num>
</value>
```

I want to know if it is possible to access to a particular node from a node previously stored in a variable. The XSLT code is very short and explains better what I want to say

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/value/num">
        <xsl:variable name="node">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <root>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$node"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So I store the node in the variable "node". Then I can print the contents of the node with `$node`.

(EDIT) XML output

```
<root>
    <num>
        <accession>111</accession>
        <sequence>AAA</sequence>
        <score>4000</score>
    </num>
</root>
```

What I want to do is to print the contents of a sub-node, like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/value/num">
        <xsl:variable name="node">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <root>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$node/accession"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it gives an error (Component returned failure code: 0x80600008 [nsIXSLTProcessor.transformToFragment]) (check [here](http://xsltcake.com/slices/lH3JVa/3))

(EDIT) The XML that I would want is

```
<root>
    <accession>111</accession>
</root>
```

NOTE: The question is not how can I get this output. The question is how, using a variable as in the XSLT provided, can I get this output.

(EDIT:SOLVED)
Actually it is possible, but as pointed out in the comments, the value of a variable has to be assigned with the "select" attribute if a node-set is required. So this code was not working since the variable had a tree fragment instead of a node-set stored in it (read more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353668/how-to-store-node-set-in-a-variable-based-on-choose-when-condition))

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a sample expected output?

Comment: Question edited. Please note that I am not only asking for this particular output, but that I need to use a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/value">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="num">
                <xsl:variable name="node" select="current()" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="$node/accession" />
           </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Note that I used xsl:transform instead of xsl:stylesheet. Also, consider using version 2.0 instead of 1.0 if you have a compliant processor, it adds a lot of useful features.

I still don't see your need for a variable, though.

Comment: What's the difference between transform and stylesheet? [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_stylesheet.asp) they are said to be synonyms. Also, I need Firefox to process the files, so I cannot move to XSLT2 yet.

Comment: The variable is useless in this example, but I need it to store a particular node decided within a choose element. Then, with your code I can see where is the problem. If I express the `<xsl:variable name="node" select="current()"/>` as it, I have no problems. If I express the same as `<xsl:variable name="node"><xsl:copy-of select="current()"/></xsl:variable>` then I get the error. Why is that?

Comment: The copy-of element which you declared inside the variable element does not affect the variable element whatsoever. You just declared a variable without assigning anything to it. You must use the select attribute to assign it a value. The copy-of element copies the value of the selected node to the output document, not to the variable.

Comment: I see, then there is no way to assign a value to a variable other than using the select attribute? In any case, the original question is then solved, I will update the question pointing to this. Thanks!

Comment: (I can see that with the select attribute you store a node-set element, without it you select a tree fragment. So that was the root of the problem)